# How to make universal GET method for Realm objects?

Tags: ios, swift, realm

I my viewControllers I often use realm.objects(className.self) to download data from `className` table. I wanted to simplify that so I created another swift file with `get method`. 
It looks like this:

```
class Realm_manager {
    private init() {}
    static let shared = Realm_manager()

    let realm = try! Realm()
    func getObjects() -> [customType]{
            let result = realm.objects(customType.self)
            return Array(result)
        } 
}
```

But that `getObjects` method works only for `customType` objects.
With this in viewController it works fine:

```
    let result = Realm_manager.shared.getObjects()
    for item in result {
            myArray.append(item)
        }
    //this works because myArray is of type customType.
```

I want to make getObjects universal method which can accept any class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [Generics](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Generics.html)

```
class RealmManager {
    private init() {}
    static let shared = RealmManager()

    let realm = try! Realm()

    func getObjects<T: Object>() -> [T] {
        let result = realm.objects(T.self)
        return Array(result)
    } 
}
```

usage:

```
let manager = RealmManager.shared
let dogs: [Dogs] = manager.getObjects()
```

Note: In Swift we generally do not use underscores in Type names, they are normally upper camel cased. Realm_manager -> RealmManager

Comment: Thanks for naming advice.
Got this error in last line of your code: `Cannot explicitly specialize a generic function`.

Comment: oh, let me double check it, 2 mins

Comment: I think I found a solution, check this and edit your code if you think this is ok(works for me) : let result : [Dog] = manager.getObjects()

Comment: Yes that works, good spot. I was wondering what the issue was there :)

Comment: I have just posted another question with similar problem, I hope you can check it :)

Comment: @faris97 Hold up. While I like this answer, it's going to create memory issues. Realm objects are lazily loaded so whether Results contain 10 or 10,000 objects the memory impact is negligible. Realm objects are also live and auto updating so as an object is changed, that change is reflected live. This `return Array(result)` changes all of that behavior and will cause ALL of the objects to load into memory at once (possibly overwhelming the device; they are no longer lazily loaded) and more importantly will loose their live connection to the Realm.